# Passing textbox currently in focus

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a application with 4 textbox controls: `TotalTextBox`, `PaidTextBox`, `RemainingTextBox` and `DriverTextBox`.

How do I pass through the current textbox in focus by the user (only if it is not `DriverTextBox`, i.e. only from `TotalTextBox`, `PaidTextBox`, `RemainingTextBox`)?

On program launch it should focus on the TotalTextBox control. I have also implemented a try/catch so that it only defaults back to focusing on the TotalTextBox control.

This is my code so far:

**MainWindow.Xaml.cs** (where tb is the Textbox in focus I want to pass through)

```
public MainWindow()
{
            InitializeComponent();
            TotalTextBox.Focus();

            // Setup keypad
            bool dotControl = false;
            int count = 0;
}

private void RemoveLastButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        var keypadObject = new Keypad();
        keypadObject.RemoveLast(TextBox tb, bool dotControl, int count);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {
        TotalTextBox.Focus();
    }
}
```

**Keypad.cs**

```
public void RemoveLast(TextBox tb, bool dotControl, int count)
{
    if (tb.Text.Length > 0)
    {
        if (char.IsDigit(tb.Text[tb.Text.Length - 1])) count = 0;
        else
        {
            dotControl = false;
            count = 0;
        }
        tb.Text = tb.Text.Remove(tb.Text.Length - 1, 1);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To get the currently focused textbox, you can do something like this:

```
TextBox textbox = Keyboard.FocusedElement as TextBox;
```

If `textbox` ends up being `null`, then it's not a textbox that is currently focused.

To complete the answer, you can filter what you want by simple comparison to your known textboxes.

```
if (textbox != null && textbox != DriverTextBox)
{
    var keypadObject = new Keypad();
    keypadObject.RemoveLast(textbox, dotControl, count);
}
```